# Laravel 4 db seed specific seeder file

Tags: database, laravel-4

I have an existing user table with information seeded via `db:seed` from UserSeeder.php. Now, I am adding new product table and want to seed information into product table. How can I prevent Laravel from seeding the UserSeeder into the database, but only the new ProductSeeder being seeded?

Thanks.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You can call individual seed classes by their class name.
From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/seeding#running-seeders).

> By default, the db:seed command runs the DatabaseSeeder class, which
>   may be used to call other seed classes. However, you may use the
>   --class option to specify a specific seeder class to run individually:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=ProductTableSeeder
```

In the example above, the `ProductTableSeeder` class should exist in `database/seeds`.

Comment: You'll need to provide the namespaced path in the following format if you namespace your seeder:

```Vendor\\Foo\\Seeders\\DatabaseSeeder```

Comment: Don't forget to run `composer dump-autoload` if you've just created the new seeder. Otherwise you'll get "Class XySeeder does not exist"

Comment: Still works on Laravel 8+

Comment: Works for Laravel 9+

Comment: In case you are not able run `composer dump-autoload` and getting "Class XySeeder does not exist" error.

You can manually update:
vendor/composer/autoload_classmap
vendor/composer/autoload_static

add your seeder class and run the command mentioned into answer

Answer (score 17):

Here's a working example with the class full namespace:

Should use double backslashes `\\`.

Class name is `DefaultBannersSeeder`.

```
php artisan db:seed --class=App\\Containers\\Banners\\Data\\Seeders\\DefaultBannersSeeder
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit your `database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php` file's `$this->call()` instruction:

```
<?php
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call([
            UserTableSeeder::class,
            PermissionsSeeder::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put my seeders in folders in accordance with their meaning.
I have `LookupSeeders`, `DemoSeeders`, `TestSeeders`...

for example I need to run this seeder - `project\database\seeds\LookupSeeders\CountrySeeder.php`

This is how you can do it... say from `project\tests\autoload.php` file

```
echo shell_exec('php artisan db:seed --class=LookupSeeders\\\\CountrySeeder');
```